# how to implement keyword search in CouchDB

Tags: java, search, lucene, couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I am new to CouchDB. How to implement keyword search in CouchDB?

For example, I have users document in CouchDB. The structure is the following:

```
UsersCouchDB:

id: 1
last_name: jack
first_name: abc
phone_num: 123-456-7890

id: 2
last_name: rose
first_name: gbcde
phone_num: 123-111-2222

...
```

I want to implement a search function for phone_num, so that if users type in, let's say, "23", then id 1 and id 2 should be shown because their phone number contain "23".

What is the easier or fastest way to do it?
Is it possible **not** to use 3rd party package to do this feature?

I heard some people use couchdb-lucene to do the similar thing. Can anyone show me some codes about how to make this kind of search features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The easiest way** is to use [list functions](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html). However, this is equivalent to full scan operation:

```
function(head, req){
  var filter = function(key){ 
    if (!req.query.q){
      return key; // list all
    }
    if (!req.query.q.match('^[\d-]+$'){
      return; // don't allow regex injections
    }
    var match = key.match('.*' + req.query.q + '.*');
    if (match) return match[0];
  }
  start({'headers': {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});
  var num = null;
  while(row=getRow()){
    num = filter(row.key);
    if (num){
      send(num + '\n');
    }
  }
}
```

Also define view that emits phone numbers for contacts:

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.type == 'contact'){emit(doc.phone_num, null)}
}
```

And call with view that emits only contacts like: `/db/_design/contacts/_list/search/phone?q=23`

**The fastest way** is to use [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene).

First, create index ddoc:

```
{
    "_id":"_design/contacts",
    "fulltext": {
        "by_phone": {
            "index":"function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.phone_num); return ret }"
        }
    }
}
```

And query it like `http://localhost:5984/db/_fti/_design/contacts/by_phone?q=23`